# Perform logic on HTML post form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I have a simple HTML form that is posting to a URL like this...

```
<form>
    <select name="option_dropdown">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <input class="textinput1" type="text"></input>
    <input class="textinput2" type="text"></input>
    <input class="textinput2" type="text"></input>
</form>
```

This generates a URL like this **www.example.com/?option_dropdown=option1** when submitted, it does not include the text input boxes as they do not have a name attatched to them.

What I would like to do is add some logic to the text inputs that will choose one depending on its content and then include that parameter when the form is submitted.

Is javascript the way to achieve this?

Comment: do you want to submit content of any of these 3 text boxes based on some condition..?

Comment: Yes, some sort of logic that chooses which of the boxes to submit

Answer (score 1):

You ask for `javascript way` so you can try this.

In order to identify 3 textboxes i've given id's to them.

```
<form>
    <select name="option_dropdown">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <input class="textinput1"  id='txt1' type="text"></input>
    <input class="textinput2"  id='txt2' type="text"></input>
    <input class="textinput2"  id='txt3' type="text"></input>
    <input type='submit' id='submit'>
</form>
```

on submitting this form script will add name property to any of the 3 text boxes based on a logic of yours. so only that textbox content will be submitted.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

     /* Any logic which select the textbox to be submitted */
     id='txt1'; // it can be txt2 or txt3

     $("#submit").click(function(){
         $("#"+id).attr("name","text");  
     });

 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a PHP file in the same directory as the html.
2.Edit your form to point to that php file and name your text fields so you could refer to them.

```
<form method="post" action="formTester.php">
  <select name="option_dropdown">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
  </select>
  <input name="textinput1" class="textinput1" type="text"></input>
  <input name="textinput2" class="textinput2" type="text"></input>
  <input name="textinput3" class="textinput2" type="text"></input>
</form>
```

3. In your file formTester.php

```
<?php 
  // define variables and and get data from the text fields

  $text1= $_POST["textinput1"]; 

  $text2= $_POST["textinput2"]; 

  $text3= $_POST["textinput3"];

 // Now you can manipulate the data however you want ..add it to database, trim, validate etc 

?>
```

Hope it helps,
Best

Answer (score -1):

```
<form>
    <select name="option_dropdown">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="textinput1" name="textinput[]" value="input1" />
    <input type="text" class="textinput2" name="textinput[]" value="input2" />
    <input type="text" class="textinput3" name="textinput[]" value="input3" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

One option is to stack your values in an array and parse it on the backend. This removes the need for JavaScript.

```
<form>
    <select name="option_dropdown">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="textinput1" name="textinput[]"></input>
    <input type="text" class="textinput2" name="textinput[]"></input>
    <input type="text" class="textinput3" name="textinput[]"></input>
</form>
```